# How to test a NSDate with a wrong NSDateFormatter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm working on iPhone application where the user can enter a date format as he want.
The problem is when he does not enter a valid format.
I don't know how to test it ?

For example, he enter :
Format = `@"evlzuhbpùi égkjz $çà i,ùé'po";`

I calculate my current date from this wrong format :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:Format];
NSString *stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"%@", stringDate);
[dateFormatter release];
```

My string date has a wrong value or hasn't a correct value.

Is anyone can tell me how to test my date format ?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Though you choose to validate the `dateFormat` with valid date format specifiers, it will be really hard to come up with a logic that validates the `dateFormat` with all the possible valid formats.

A simple but optimal solution would be to convert the converted `date string` back to `NSDate` with the `same dateFormat`. If the resultant date is `nil`, the definitely the `dateFormat` is an invalid one.

```
// Set the dateFormat to NSDateFormatter
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:Format];

// Get a string from NSDate using the date formatt
NSString *stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

// Convert "stringDate" to NSDate with the same dateFormat
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];

if (date == nil)  // The dateFormat is not a valid one
else // The dateFormat seems to be valid
```